# Getting Access to send emails to dynamic addresses

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This is in Access 2010 and I have virtually no experience or familiarity with VBA.

In my form (frmEmailLookup), I have combo boxes and list boxes and a subform set up so that when the user selects a building from cmbBuilding the remainder of the form populates with the data on that building, including the contact emails for up to 4 people in the building (lstBuildingRepEmail1, lstBuildingRepEmail2, lstBuildingRepEmail3, lstBuildingRepEmail4). I need a button (butEmailRecords) to generate an email with the query from the subform (qryBuildingAreaLookup) as an attachment. I can set up a macro that will something close, but it doesn't allow for dynamic email addresses. I don't want my users to have to go that far into the program to make updates.

Any help is appreciated and I know I'm asking for a lot of code writing help.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    Option Compare Database
Private Sub butEmailRecords_Click()
Dim outputFileName As String
outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\BuildingInventory" & ".xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,      acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "qryBuildingAreaLookup",     outputFileName, True

On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryBuildinAreaLookup")
With rs

With objEmail
.To = tblBuilding.BuildingRep1
.To = tblBuilding.BuildingRep2
.To = tblBuilding.BuildingRep3
.To = tblBuilding.BuildingRep4
.Subject = "Look at this sample attachment"
.body = "The body doesn't matter, just the attachment"
.Attachments.Add "L:\Administration\FacilityInventoryDatabase\BuildingInventory.xls    x"
.Send
'.ReadReceiptRequested
End With
Exit_Here:
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
Resume Exit_Here
End Sub
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow - generally you will need to post some code that you have attempted with a specific issue that is not working - this question is pretty vague and demands other people to do your work for you - which will likely be closed.

Comment: I have a macro for emails and it uses a loop to grab all the emails of the users based on what department it needs to go through.  Then the only thing that needs updating is the employee list.

Comment: Thanks TKEyi60. Do you use the EMailDatabaseObject macro? if so how do you get the "To" to reference a field in a table?

Comment: And what error does that throw if any?  Or what does it do/not do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basics of what I use:

```
'Refers to Outlook's Application object
Dim appOutlook As Object

'Refers to an Outlook email message
Dim appOutlookMsg As Object

'Refers to an Outlook email recipient
Dim appOutlookRec As Object

'Create an Outlook session in the background
Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Create a new empty email message
Set appOutlookMsg = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Using the new, empty message...
With appOutlookMsg

'SQL statement to grab emails

Set recordset = currentdb.openrecordset('SQL statement')

Do While Not recorset.EOF
Set appOutlookRec = .Recipients.Add(recordset.Email)
appOutlookRec.Type = olTo
recordset.MoveNext
Loop

.Subject = ....
.Body = ....
.Send

End With
```

and that's the basics of what I use.  I'm a beginner so this may not be the best way, but it should be a start.  (I also had to add Microsoft Oulook in the reference library.)

Comment: in the set resordset = currentdb.openrecordset section this is where i refer to the query that I want sent as an attachment, right?

Comment: I imagine you could set it as an attachment, but I'm not sure how to actually attach anything via VBA.  Mine only writes in the body and my query pulls email addresses and put those in the recipients field.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just try asking again with how far I'v gotten.

Answer (score 0):

I use CDO objects to send messages because I prefer not to rely on Outlook (for anything).

There is quite a comprehensive article on using CDO to send mail (including downloadable VBA code) here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Email.aspx